# How to change Missile direction in Space Rocks of Chapter 7 of Gary Rosenzweig's book: "Action Script 3.0 game programming university"

Tags: actionscript-3

I have been trying to play with the source code of Space Rocks used as an example in Chapter 7 of Gary Rosenzweig's book "Action Script 3.0 game programming university" and he has used a ball to avoid missile direction. However, I am trying to make the game a bit more creative. The problem I have come across is that if you design a missile sprite that is directional ie a bullet the source code will always fire that bullet upright. It doesn't rotate the bullet in line with the ship. Unfortunately I am stumped. Here is the code used to create and animate the missile.

// MISSILES

```
    // create a new Missile
    public function newMissile() {
        // create
        var newMissile:Missile = new Missile();

        // set direction
        newMissile.dx = Math.cos(Math.PI*ship.rotation/180);
        newMissile.dy = Math.sin(Math.PI*ship.rotation/180);

        // placement
        newMissile.x = ship.x + newMissile.dx*shipRadius;
        newMissile.y = ship.y + newMissile.dy*shipRadius;

        // add to stage and array
        gameObjects.addChild(newMissile);
        missiles.push(newMissile);
    }

    // animate missiles
    public function moveMissiles(timeDiff:uint) {
        for(var i:int=missiles.length-1;i>=0;i--) {
            // move

            missiles[i].x += missiles[i].dx*missileSpeed*timeDiff;
            missiles[i].y += missiles[i].dy*missileSpeed*timeDiff;
            // moved off screen
            if ((missiles[i].x < 0) || (missiles[i].x > 550) || (missiles[i].y < 0) || (missiles[i].y > 400)) {
                gameObjects.removeChild(missiles[i]);
                delete missiles[i];
                missiles.splice(i,1);
            }
        }
    }
```

Many Thanks
Shane

Comment: have you tried `newMissle.rotation = ship.rotation;`?

Comment: Thanks! That worked! I didn't even think of that. I was playing with the animate function. Greatly appreciated!